# Is it compulsory to use Firebase to use social login (Google, Facebook, Apple login) in flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, facebook-login, google-signin

I am trying to implement a social logins in flutter app and i don't want to use Firebase, I have explored on google and development forums all mostly suggests firebase for the same. Can i any one help me out of this 
It will be better if one can suggest plugin/plugins for social login mainly in google, facebook, twitter and apple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer is NO.

Flutter is not strictly tied to Firebase, firebase is only one option.

There is a dart package https://pub.dev/packages/social_login, and you can use FaceBook account etc. for such purposes.

```
// Import package
import 'package:social_login/social_login.dart';

// Instantiate it
 final socialLogin = SocialLogin();

//Before calling any methods, set the configuration
socialLogin.setConfig(SocialConfig(
      facebookAppId: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
      googleWebClientId: GOOGLE_WEB_CLIENT_ID, /*In case a Google tokenId is needed*/
      twitterConsumer: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
      twitterSecret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    ));

// Get current logged user
 final FacebookUser facebookUser = await socialLogin.getCurrentFacebookUser();
 final GoogleUser googleUser = await socialLogin.getCurrentGoogleUser();
 final TwitterUser twitterUser = await socialLogin.getCurrentTwitterUser();
```

Comment: thanks for answer david but i am facing issue even after changing value of app id and web client in config i am still getting error saying 

`flutter: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method login_twitter on channel com.wembleystudios.social_login)`